# Tables & Javascript: Which formats are best? How do I extract arrays from a table?

Tags: javascript, html-table

Been asked to do define a function that takes an HTML table containing a persons age and weight and returns the mode of all weights for people within a given age range. The function should work with tables of any length. What is the best way to filter rows by a person's age and then convert all qualifying rows in an array (i.e. extract the filtered weight column). I'd like to do the following, although I realize I can't reference an HTML table using square bracket notation. Is there something comparable for HTML tables in JavaScript? I'm interested in learning the best way to work with HTML tables in Javascript in general, the specifics of this problem aren't important.

```js
function birthWeightByAge(ageWeightTbl, rowCount, minVal, maxVal) {
    var weightArray = [];
    //Traverse table by row
    for (var i =0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        //Determine age and weight for this row. Can I use this approach with different syntax? Do I need to use a completely different approach?
        var age = ageWeightTbl[i][0];
        var weight = ageWeightTbl[i][1];
        //Check if the baby weight in this row meets the requirements
        if (weight > minVal && weight < maxVal) {
            //If it does, add the age and weight to our holding arrays
            ageArray.push(age);
            weightArray.push(weight);
        }
    }
  
    var weightMode = mode(weightArray);
  }
```

Side Question: Is there a data format that will render on an HTML page, but that is easier to work with in Javascript? If yes, please provide an high level overview of its benefits and how it works.

I've added a sample table as requested:

```js
//Helper function that creates a mock table for testing
function generate_table(rows) {
  // get the reference for the body
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
 
  // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
  var tbl     = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
 
  // creating all cells
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    // creates a table row
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
 
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
      // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
      // the end of the table row
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
        if (j<1) {
            var cellText = document.createTextNode(""+Math.round(100*Math.random())+"");
        }
        else {
            var cellText = document.createTextNode(""+Math.round(10*Math.random())+"");
        }
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
 
    // add the row to the end of the table body
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
 
  // put the <tbody> in the <table>
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  // appends <table> into <body>
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
  tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}

//Sample Output: {"Mode": 9}
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you define a mock table set, that the function will take, and what you expect to be handed back from the function.

Comment: I've added the code for a sample table and a sample output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Give your table an `id` attribute (I added the following line to your "mock table" function: `tbl.id = "weightAgeTable";`).

Then, call the following function, using that `id` value as the first argument:

```
function birthWeightByAge(tableId, rowCount, minVal, maxVal) {
    var weightArray = [];
    var ageArray = [];
    var tbl = document.getElementById(tableId);

    //Traverse table by row
    for (var i =0; i < rowCount; i++) {

        //Determine age and weight for this row
        var weight = tbl.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML; //var weight = ageWeightTbl[i][1];
        var age = tbl.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML; //var age = ageWeightTbl[i][0];

        //Check if the baby weight in this row meets the requirements
        if (weight > minVal && weight < maxVal) {
            //If it does, add the age and weight to our holding arrays
            ageArray.push(age);
            weightArray.push(weight);
        }
    }

    console.log(weightArray); // var weightMode = mode(weightArray);
}
```

I don't have your `mode` function, so I commented it and output the array to the console instead, for demo purposes.

Also, I think your "mock table" function may have reversed the columns, which is why my `.cells` numbers are reversed from yours.

Comment: Thanks! That was awesome. Way simpler than anything else I've found.